# Creating an ApplicationUser navigation property using UserName as the foreign key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a CreatedBy field on my entities where the logged in user's UserName is stored. I would like to create a navigation property on the entity as well.

The properties of my entity look like this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
// public ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

How can I make the CreatedByUser navigation property actually work. I would like it to automatically be retrieved when I use "Include" in my queries so I have access to the:

> Product.CreatedByUser.FirstName and Product.CreatedByUser.LastName.

I know this will easily work if I choose to store UserId rather than UserName in the CreatedBy field, but most people store the UserName in a CreatedBy field since it is easy to access through the Current HttpContext. I would also like to keep it this way for clarity in the database, rather than having a bunch of guids.

Comment: Can you show Entity ApplicationUser and it's configuration?

Comment: @gsharp There isn't anything to it. Just the default IdentityUser that comes with ASP.NET Core Identity. I added two additional properties FirstName and LastName.

Comment: "I would also like to keep it this way for clarity in the database, rather than having a bunch of guids". It is actually the opposite - you get clarity by using unique IDs and GUIDs across your database, and not using them creates a mess. Imagine you have 150000 products created by user "user1" and now you need to change his username. Are you going to update 150 000 rows in Products table? :)

Comment: @BlakeRivell Hi!, I have answered your question but you didn't say anything whether it has worked for you not? Would be great if you let me know your feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can do this by using Entity Framework Core [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys) feature as follows:

Your Entity:

```
public class YourEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; } 
}
```

Then in the Model Configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
        .HasOne(e => e.CreatedByUser)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedBy)
        .HasPrincipalKey(cu => cu.UserName);
}
```